# Call gnuplot.exe without command prompt popping up & stealing focus of top window

Tags: gnuplot

Ok guys, please help me. How to call "gnuplot.exe" from within my program without it 
a) showing a cmd window for half a second, and then
b) not the window that was just in focus is on top, but the one below.

So it does not only screw shit up through showing a cmd.exe, it also messes around with the top window.

I tired to call it through

1. start /MIN gnuplot.exe CMDFILE
2. start gnuplot.exe CMDFILE
3. cmd.exe /C "start /MIN gnuplot.exe CMDFILE"
4. cmd.exe /C "gnuplot.exe CMDFILE"

All this with system() and CreateProcessA with SW_HIDE; STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW  &&  CREATE_NO_WINDOW

When I use the 1. approach from within a command promt there is no additional cmd.

If I use 2. with CreateProcess it at least does not steal the top window's focus.

Btw: everything was tried with gnuplot.exe, pgnuplot.exe & wgnuplot.exe

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact details of what you are trying to do, what you probably need here is gnuplot's -persist option. That will keep gnuplot running after your command is executed.

```
gnuplot.exe -persist CMDFILE
```

Comment: Hey, but I want to have the opposite. gnuplot should just not appear, it should execute CMDFILE and then end.
But it should do so without showing a cmd window :)

Comment: Sorry, read your initial post to quickly. What language are you programming in? In Python, the kind of behaviour you ar looking for is achieved using only STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW for STARTUPINFO

Comment: No problem :) Already tried that:
"[I have tested] all this with system() and CreateProcessA with SW_HIDE && STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW && CREATE_NO_WINDOW"

sadly, it has no effect. Tough this is working well for GUI programs :)